# Rails, hash failing when assigned to variable, but showing correct output when aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

This should be an easy one. I have a method in my model that is doing this:

```
my_hash.max_by{ |k,v| v}[0]
```

I'm trying to get the key of the maximum value in the hash (by converting it to an array). If I do the following I get my **intended** results:

```
abort my_hash.max_by{ |k,v| v}[0]  # Honda (for example)
```

When I do this, I get a undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

```
brand =  my_hash.max_by{ |k,v| v}[0]
```

What am I missing? Any thoughts or guesses are appreciated!

**EDIT**
my_hash
{"Honda"=> 4, "Toyota"=>2, "Ford"=>1}

The code was working when I have it directly in my view. Once I move it to the model and try and assign it to a variable, I get the above error.

Comment: Please add your `my_hash`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the key, value pair you are using in my_hash ?

I have tried this, and it is working for me:

```
irb(main):008:0> my_hash = {"CA"=>2, "MI"=>1, "NY"=>1}
=> {"CA"=>2, "MI"=>1, "NY"=>1}
irb(main):009:0> brand = my_hash.max_by{ |k,v| v}[0]
=> "CA"
```

Comment: {"Honda"=> 4, "Toyota"=>2, "Ford"=>1} The code was working when I have it directly in my view. Once I move it to the model and try and assign it to a variable, I get the above error.

Comment: @Aptorian Please share the code you have written on model and also for assigning the value into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `my_hash` variable must be either an empty hash `{}` or array `[]` in your model. I think that it's the only way you'll get the error you observe.